# Error in map(ID=0) -- Cannot Interpret <Image> as a date

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am refactoring code from the Javascript API to the Python API to aid in exporting. The following code works in the Javascript API:

```
var banded_images = ee.ImageCollection(ee_dates.map(build_annual_cube))

var sample_from_collection = function(d){
  var startDate = (ee.Date(d).advance(1.0,'year').millis())
  var endDate = ee.Date(d).advance(2.0,'year').millis()
  
  var pointsInThatYear = carp.filterDate(startDate,endDate)
  
  var img_in_that_year = ee.Image(banded_images.filterDate(startDate,endDate).first())
  
  
  var presence_samp = img_in_that_year.sampleRegions({
                              'collection':pointsInThatYear,
                              'scale': 30,
                              'properties':['Present'],
                              'tileScale':16
                            })
    
    return presence_samp
}

var presence_samp = ee_dates.map(sample_from_collection)
print(presence_samp.get(1))
```

Where `var banded_images` is an image collection containing a series of images with various bands, each embedded with a `system:time_start` property. `var carp` is a feature collection filled with location information. What I am trying to do is extract temporally explicit covariates from the banded image.

However, when translating to the python API, I get the following cryptic error message:

`Error in map(ID=0): Date: Cannot interpret <Image<[List of bands]>> as a Date.`

I have searched far and wide and can't find this specific error code anywhere. Here is my python-translated script:

```
banded_images = ee.ImageCollection(ee_dates.map(build_annual_cube))


def sample_from_collection(d):
    #Set start and end dates for filtering time dependent predictors (SR, NDVI, Phenology)
      #Advance startDate by 1 to begin with to account for water year (below)
    startDate = (ee.Date(d).advance(1.0,'year').millis())
    endDate = ee.Date(d).advance(2.0,'year').millis()
    
     # Filter points by dates
    pointsInThatYear = carp.filterDate(startDate,endDate) # <---- CHANGE ACCORDING TO SPECIES OF INTEREST
    
    # Filter collection by that year
    img_in_that_year = ee.Image(banded_images.filterDate(startDate,endDate).first())
    
    
    # Sample that image
    presence_samp = img_in_that_year.sampleRegions(**{
                                'collection':pointsInThatYear,
                                'scale': 30,
                                'properties':['Present'],
                                'tileScale':16
                              })
    
    return presence_samp


presence_sample = banded_images.map(sample_from_collection)
```

A link to the Javascript script can be found below, with all relevant assets shared

https://code.earthengine.google.com/094e0b2aa185bcb892d7c0958eea57c6

**Edit:** I underwent a rather tedious debugging process where I ran the following code for each date in the ee_dates list:

```
d = ee.Date("2017-01-01")
startDate = (ee.Date(d).advance(1.0,'year').millis())
endDate = ee.Date(d).advance(2.0,'year').millis() 

pointsInThatYear = carp.filterDate(startDate,endDate) # <---- CHANGE ACCORDING TO SPECIES OF INTEREST

data = pointsInThatYear.getInfo()


img_in_that_year = ee.Image(banded_images.filterDate(startDate,endDate).first())

# Sample that image
presence_samp = img_in_that_year.sampleRegions(**{
                            'collection':pointsInThatYear,
                            'scale': 30,
                            'properties':['Present'],
                            'tileScale':16
                          })
print(presence_samp)
```

I was able to run this code with every single year of interest. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the wrong variable. In the JavaScript version you have:

```
var presence_samp = ee_dates.map(sample_from_collection)
```

But in Python you wrote `banded_images` instead of `ee_dates`:

```
presence_sample = banded_images.map(sample_from_collection)
```

This accounts for the error because you are passing an image from a collection to code that expects a date.